# Possible for roslaunch to respawn node after power failure on remote machine?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to set up power failure or intermittent comms resiliency for remote nodes, and I'm not sure if I need to create a custom solution or if roslaunch might be able to do this for me.

My simple test has not yielded positive results but I'm not sure if that's expected.

My simple test situation has indicated that respawn="true" only covers if the single process that represents the remote node goes down will the node be respawned.  If roslaunch is taken down or any parent process, it looks like it will not respawn.

My gut says there's not any real way around this, but I figure I should ask:

Can `roslaunch` handle respawning remote nodes where remote connection is lost or remote machine goes down via powerfailure?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40501/possible-for-roslaunch-to-respawn-node-after-power-failure-on-remote-machine?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-08-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe roslaunch is robust to the remote machine going down.

It has a process management process on the remote machine and I don't think it has the logic to respawn the remote process management process if the machine goes down.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1